# Go command works in VS Code Terminal but doesn't in Server Command Line

Tags: go, environment-variables, .profile

I have installed Go1.14.3 on my remote server which is on a private network. When I remote SSH my VS Code to that server to work on my Go Project located at ~/BBS/r1rm/tools/DSMigrateWeb, I can see Go1.14.3 in the VS Code taskbar. Even when I run go command from "VS Code terminal", it executes and shows the desired output.

> jaydev1642@linuxjaydev:~/BBS/r1rm/tools/DSMigrateWeb$ go
> Go is a tool for managing Go source code.

Then when I migrate to a different directory in "VS Code terminal" itself and run the go command, then too it works fine but do the same on command line for any directory and I get the error as "Command 'go' not found".

> jaydev1642@linuxjaydev:~/BBS/r1rm/tools/DSMigrateWeb$ go
>
> Command 'go' not found, but can be installed with:
>
> sudo snap install go         # version 1.20.6, or
> sudo apt  install golang-go  # version 2:1.13~1ubuntu2
> sudo apt  install gccgo-go   # version 2:1.13~1ubuntu2
>
> See 'snap info go' for additional versions.

Here is my .profile file containing GOROOT and PATH variables:

> export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
>
> export GOPATH=usr/local/go/bin:/home/jaydev1642/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:
> /bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

I am not sure why I am facing this issue where Go exists if I try to access it from VS Code Terminal but doesn't when I do from command line. I also restarted the server just in case that might help but it doesn't.

Comment: That profile is loaded by VS Code because you're working on a Go project. It won't be loaded in a normal terminal window. Only commands in folders in PATH (not GOPATH) can be executed in normal terminals

Comment: I'm not pretty much sure about this but the following worked for me, 
export GOPATH=$HOME/go   //go refers to my folder location 
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:$GOPATH/bin
I have added these in my .profile file and restarted the server. Hope this helps.

Comment: You should never need to set `GOROOT`, and it is very unlikely you need to set `GOPATH`. Not to mention `GOPATH` is not a list of directories to search for commands. You presumably meant to `export PATH=...`.